# What happens if an exception occur before than static local variables are initialized?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, static-initialization

When are static local variables initialized?
If an exception is thrown in a constructor, is the object considered constructed? Will the destructor  be called?

consider fallowing code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

int x = 0;

class A {
public:
  A() {
    std::cout << 'a';
    if (x++ == 0) {
      throw std::exception();
    }
  }
  ~A() { std::cout << 'A'; }
};

class B {
public:
  B() { std::cout << 'b'; }
  ~B() { std::cout << 'B'; }
  A a;
};

void foo() { static B b; }

int main() {
  try {
    foo();
  }
  catch (std::exception &) {
    std::cout << 'c';
    foo();
  }
}
```

**output : acabBA**

The first time foo() is called, b is attempted initialized. Its constructor is called, which first constructs all member variables. This means A::A() is called, printing a. A::A() then throws an exception, the constructor is aborted, and neither b or B::a are actually considered constructed.

why b was not initialized the first time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initialization of a block-scope variable with static storage duration is attempted every time control passes over the variable definition until it succeeds.

From [stmt.dcl]/4:

> Dynamic initialization of a block-scope variable with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage
>   duration (3.7.2) is performed the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered
>   initialized upon the completion of its initialization. **If the initialization exits by throwing an exception, the
>   initialization is not complete, so it will be tried again the next time control enters the declaration.**

The construction of an object of type `B` can of course not complete if the construction of any of its members throws an exception.

Comment: and in order of destruction  of static variable it wont have any affect ?

Comment: @Adib: I don't understand - effect on what? Static variables are destroyed in reverse order of their construction (but of course this is only relevant if construction actually took place).

Comment: yes exactly i wanted to know this as static varible was not constructed before exception then it wont change order of destruction . right ?

Comment: @Adib: Only objects get destroyed. If there is no object, there is nothing to destroy.